# Replace unwanted values of factor level with NA

Tags: r, na, r-factor

I have a large data frame that contains both blank missing values and NA's. 
Performing summary(factor(df$col)) gives me something like

```
A  
123  
B  
50000  

90000  
C  
26000
NA's  
12476
```

(Notice the blank after `50000`.)
and `sum(is.na(df$col))` is 12476, the same as the number of `NA`'s, but I'd like it to be the sum of the blanks and the `NA`s.
I tried to create a level for the blanks by doing
`levels(df$col) <- c("A", "B", "Blank", "C")`
And then trying `df$col <- factor(df$col, exclude="Blank")` and it says that the `NA`'s were generated but my output is the same. Does anyone know how to create NAs based on a factor level or have a better solution for replacing the missing values? I think the issue might be that the blanks are more than one white space character, so they didn't get turned into `NA`'s but I don't know how to confirm that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df <- data.frame(a=11:18, col=c("C", "", "A", NA, "A", "", "C", NA))
levels(df$col) # ""  "A" "C"
sum(is.na(df$col)) # 2

df$col <- factor(df$col, levels=LETTERS[1:3])
levels(df$col) # "A" "B" "C"
sum(is.na(df$col)) # 4
```

Since the new levels do not include blank (""), all blanks will become NA.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for me because my factor levels are not actually called A:C. I tried the equivalent of levels(df$col) <- c("A", "B", "Blank", "C") and df$col <- factor(df$col, levels=c("A", "B", "C")) and that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I did levels(df$col) <- c(LETTERS[1:2], "Blank", LETTERS[3]) and df$col <- factor(df$col, levels=LETTERS[1:3]) and this worked. Thank you so much for the help.